# How to check SQL query against object instance in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` class in a Rails app. I have a way of creating a custom SQL query programmatically. I want to them know if the `User` passes the conditions in that query. That is to say, essentially I have:

```
where = 'administrator OR (roles_mask & 4)'
```

and I want to know if that is true for my `@user` variable. Currently I have:

```
passes = User.where("(#{where}) AND id = ?", @user.id).any?
```

but that doesn't exactly seem right. Any suggestions?

------ *EDIT* ------
The where variable is constructed here:

```
where = Array(overrides).map do |override_group|
  if User::ROLES.include?(override_group.to_s)
    "(roles_mask & #{2 ** User::ROLES.index(override_group.to_s)})"
  else
    override_group.to_s
  end
end.join(' OR ')
```

Comment: You should never use direct string interpolation in SQL queries (SQL injections are possible with String Interpolation). Eventually use  sanitize to make the input safe: `.where("(#{sanitize(where)}) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a scope and a simple where clause here:

```
scope :admin_or_mask_4, { where('administrator OR (roles_mask & 4)') }

passes = User.admin_or_mask_4.where(id: @user.id).exists?
```

---

**After your edit**:

(I renamed your local variable `where` to `conditions` because where is an ActiveRecord method, and executed in a Model context this code could provoke conflicts)

```
conditions = Array(overrides).map do |override_group|
  if User::ROLES.include?(override_group.to_s)
    "(roles_mask & #{2 ** User::ROLES.index(override_group.to_s)})"
  else
    override_group.to_s
  end
end.join(' OR ')

passes = User.where(conditions).where(id: @user.id).exists?
```

Comment: The thing is, that where variable is dynamic. It could be `'administrator OR (roles_mask & 4)'` or it could be something like `'administrator AND !superuser AND active AND roles_mask & 32'`

Comment: How do you build it? I need more infos about this query, I can't help you with this few elements in mind...

Comment: I put it in the question.